# I want to interpret an audio file on my Raspberrry Pi. Does anybody has some experience with this? (Audio interpreter)

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I want to use a radio scanner to listen to some frequences. The audio output should go into my Raspberry Pi, where I want to interpret it.

For example the scanner detects a frequence ->  Somebody says: "Hello, World." -> I want to display "Hello World" on my monitor.

Later I want to interpret the text more.

Does anybody can tell me more about possible software/hardware solutions?
Are there, for example, libaries or templates for a use case like this?

I'm using an Raspberry Pi 4b!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Offer some perspective

1. Remove noise: Use noise reduction software or algorithm to remove noise from audio and extract human voice
2. Extract speech: Use speech recognition software or algorithms to extract speech from audio.

https://aws.amazon.com/cn/transcribe

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text

Note that the effectiveness of these software or algorithms may vary depending on the quality of the input audio, the language, the speaker's voice, and other factors. Therefore, it may take some experimentation to determine the best tool for your application scenario.